# Uso de $_REQUEST ao invés de $_GET, $_POST e $_COOKIE

Tags: php, post, cookies, get, request

Em PHP temos disponível a variável global [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) que pode ser utilizada ao invés de utilizar individualmente as variáveis globais [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) e [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).

**Por exemplo:**

```
<?php
// utilizar
$bubu = $_REQUEST['bubu'];

// ou uma das três em baixo consoante a localização:

// se via GET
$bubu = $_GET['bubu'];

// se via POST
$bubu = $_POST['bubu'];

// se num Cookie
$bubu = $_COOKIE['bubu'];
?>
```

Tendo em conta a leitura do código e respectiva eficiência, o uso da variável `$_REQUEST` trás mais valias face a um uso mais especifico através das outras três variáveis indicadas ou ao utilizar `$_REQUEST` estar-se-ia a complicar?

Answer (score 8):

Depende da confiança que tenha nos dados vindos do cliente. 
Se tiver a certeza que não existe nenhuma chave repetida, ou seja que não há um envio simultâneo de `$_GET['bubu']`, `$_POST['bubu']`, `$_COOKIE['bubu']` não vejo qualquer problema em usar o `$_REQUEST`.

Agora se houver repetição de alguma chave vai acontecer o seguinte:

```
<?php

setcookie("search","valueA")

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9'>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "GET =" .$_GET['search'] . "<br>";
echo "COOKIE =".$_COOKIE['search']. "<br>";
echo "REQUEST =" .$_REQUEST['search']. "<br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

para a url

```
exemplo.com/index.php?search=valueB
```

terá os seguintes valores

```
GET =valueB
COOKIE =valueA
REQUEST =valueB
```

Isto depende da ordem definida pela diretiva "variables_order" do php.ini que define a ordem pela qual é feita a ordem do prase da variaveis

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: Acrescentando: nunca confie nos dados que um cliente pode passar, pois você nunca tem controle sobre eles. Melhor esperar por algo mais específico do que arriscar errar com algo mais genérico.

Answer (score 6):

**TL:DR**

Em questões de eficiência, não há ganho para o PHP ao acessar uma variável ou outra, porém seu uso pode gerar resultados inesperados.

---

Os malefícios em utilizar o `$_REQUEST` é de sempre utilizar o `$_REQUEST` para qualquer situação. Quando não utilizamos a variável global específica para o que queremos, estamos instruindo nosso programa a <strike>pedir "Vodka ou Água de Coco, pra mim tanto faz"¹</strike> aceitar qualquer tipo de input do usuário, o que pode não ser adequado em todos os casos.

Quando utilizamos o `$_REQUEST` o PHP prioriza a precedência das variáveis globais de acordo com a configuração [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order). Por padrão ele obedece a sequencia `EGPCS` (Environment, Get, Post, Cookie, e Server).

O usuário então pode facilmente pular alguma etapa de validação do seu sistema. Um exemplo comum que podemos encontrar é com o uso de `input hidden` em um formulário:

```
<form action="my/update/page" method="POST" onsubmit="doSomeJs()">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
    <!-- o resto do form -->
</form>
```

O usuário pode simplesmente enviar o `id` dessa forma `my/update/page?id=1`, enviando assim um parâmetro diferente.

Claro, é possível forjar uma requisição `HTTP` com `POST` modificado, mas a partir do `GET` ficaria mais simples para o usuário comum.

O uso indevido do `$_REQUEST` é ao meu ver uma brecha de segurança, não com um impacto tão grande como nos tempos de `register_global`, mas ainda assim é uma brecha que pode ser explorada.

No ponto de vista da leitura do código, fica mais difícil identificar a origem da informação usando `$_REQUEST`:

```
<?php

// Sem Request

$paginaOrigem       = $_GET['paginaOrigem'];
$id                 = $_POST['id'];
$nome               = $_POST['nome'];
$endereco           = $_POST['endereco'];
$dataUltimoAcesso   = $_COOKIE['ultimoAcesso'];

// Com Request

$paginaOrigem       = $_REQUEST['paginaOrigem'];
$id                 = $_REQUEST['id'];
$nome               = $_REQUEST['nome'];
$endereco           = $_REQUEST['endereco'];
$dataUltimoAcesso   = $_REQUEST['ultimoAcesso'];
```

**Conclusão**

Pense duas vezes antes de usar o `$_REQUEST`, e use somente quando for necessário.

<sup>¹ Referência a uma [popular música brasileira](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzS61Jennkw)</sup>