# Ao submeter formulário, os dados de GET são perdidos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tentando enviar os dados de um form para o banco de dados. Tenho dados vindo de POST e também do GET, porém ao clicar no botão submit o valor da variável que recebe dados do GET são zerados.

ESTE É O FORM.

```
<form action="pedidos.php" method="post">

<table border="1">

        <tr>
        <td> NOME DO CLIENTE  </td>
        <td> <?php echo strtoupper($nome_cliente); ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td> PRODUTO: </td>
        <td> <select name="produto">
        <?php 
            if(isset($selecionar_produto) && mysql_num_rows($selecionar_produto)){
                while($produto = mysql_fetch_array($selecionar_produto)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $produto["id_produto"]; ?>"> <?php echo $produto["nome_produto"]; ?> </option>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>  

        <tr>
        <td> QUANTIDADE: </td>
        <td> <input type="number" name="qtde"> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td> RUA: </td>
        <td> <?php echo strtoupper($rua); ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td> NÚMERO </td>
        <td> <?php echo strtoupper($num); ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td> BAIRRO </td>
        <td> <?php echo strtoupper($bairro); ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td> CIDADE: </td>
        <td> <?php echo strtoupper($cidade); ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td> STATUS </td>
        <td> 
            <select name="status">
                <?php
                    if(isset($selecionar_status) && mysql_num_rows($selecionar_status)){
                        while($status = mysql_fetch_array($selecionar_status)){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $status["id_status"];?>"> <?php echo $status["status"]; ?> </option>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="botao" value="Cadastrar"> 
        <a href="painel.php"> <input type="button" name="botao" value="Voltar"> </a>

        </td>
        </tr>               

            </select>       
        </td>
        </tr>



    </table>
</form>
```

ESTE É O PHP PARA CADASTRAR O PEDIDO

```
   if (isset($_POST["botao"]) && $_POST["botao"] == "Cadastrar"){   

        $gravar_pedidos = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedidos(id_cliente,id_produto,id_status) values ('$id_cliente','$produto','$status')");


        if(!$gravar_pedidos){
            echo "Erro ".mysql_error();
        }else{
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=painel.php'/>

            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"Operação Realizada com sucesso!!\");
            </script> ";                
        }   

}
```

Comment: edita a pergunta colocando o código do formulário html pra podermos ver como ele está e ver se o problema consiste no formulário ou no seu script. Assim que você editar a pergunta, você comenta aqui e eu dou uma olhada e vejo no que posso te ajudar.

Comment: `$id_cliente = (isset($_GET["id_cliente"]));` não está correto. Uma vez que vai ficar apenas com `true` ou `false`. O que quer fazer é `$id_cliente = ($_GET["id_cliente"]);`

Comment: Copie e cole na sua pergunta como está o html do seu formulário, e quando você mistura get e post creio que o melhor é utilizar o método que recupera ambos $_REQUEST['xxx']. [ http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.request.php ]

Comment: como faço para usar o $_REQUEST? pois estou usando o post e o get

Comment: Caso alguma resposta lhe serviu, marque-a como aceita. Veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correções a serem feitas:**

1 - Acertar o html da linha `PRODUTO`, ou seja, fechar o `select`, o `td` e o `tr`

```
    <tr>
    <td> PRODUTO: </td>
    <td> <select name="produto">
    <?php 
        if(isset($selecionar_produto) && mysql_num_rows($selecionar_produto)){
            while($produto = mysql_fetch_array($selecionar_produto)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $produto["id_produto"]; ?>"> <?php echo $produto["nome_produto"]; ?> </option>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</select></td></tr>
```

2 - Falta recuperar os valores enviados do formulário:

```
    if (isset($_POST["botao"]) && $_POST["botao"] == "Cadastrar"){  

        $id_cliente = $_POST['id_cliente'];
        $produto = $_POST['produto'];
        $status = $_POST['status']; 

        $gravar_pedidos = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedidos(id_cliente,id_produto,id_status) values ('$id_cliente','$produto','$status')");
         ......................
```

> Obs: No formulário falta um campo com valores do id_cliente e o name="id_cliente"

Você pode substituir POST por GET. Aonde houver a palavra POST substitua por GET ,ou seja,

```
<form action="pedidos.php" method="GET">

if (isset($_GET["botao"]) && $_GET["botao"] == "Cadastrar"){ 
    $id_cliente = $_GET['id_cliente'];
    $produto = $_GET['produto'];
    $status = $_GET['status'];
```

> O mais aconselhado é utilizar POST

---

### Sobre sua pergunta

"como faço para usar o $_REQUEST? pois estou usando o post e o get"

O `$_REQUEST` é o tipo genérico de de `$_GET`, `$_POST`, tanto faz se seus dados estão vindo via `$_GET` ou `$_POST`, resgata ambos.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["botao"]) && $_REQUEST["botao"] == "Cadastrar"){ 
   $id_cliente = $_REQUEST['id_cliente'];
   $produto = $_REQUEST['produto'];
   $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
```

**Nesse caso seu formulário tanto pode ser**

```
<form action="pedidos.php" method="post">
```

**quanto**

```
<form action="pedidos.php" method="GET">
```

Seu uso é pouco recomendado, saiba mais em [Uso de $_REQUEST ao invés de $_GET, $_POST e $_COOKIE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37114/uso-de-request-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-get-post-e-cookie)

Comment: Obrigada Leo era isso mesmo, nossa me ajudou muito.

Comment: Pelo que pude ver foi muita falta de atenção, ainda bem que tem essa fórum de ajuda

Answer (score 0):

sol25lua Primeiro verifique se os valores do atributo `name` do seu formulário são os mesmos do valor da super global POST.

Outra sugestão seria, atribuir os valores do POST antes do bloco `if`(e sem a função `isset()` e dentro do bloco do if você poderia continuar verificando se seu id está "setado" e a partir dai realizar o insert no banco de dados.