# Sistema de redirecionamento

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal, um problema que não consegui solucionar até o momento consiste de um sistema de login, onde se, por exemplo, o usuário já fez o login e não clicou em "SAIR" (logout), caso ele feche e volte a acessar o site, seria redirecionado para a página de usuário. Quando eu não utilizo da condição de verificar se a pessoa é classificada como "ADMIN", aparentemente tudo corre bem. Porém, ao adicionar a condição adicional de fazer essa verificação, não está funcionando.

```
<?php
    require_once 'classes/db_connect.php';
    session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_REQUEST['admin'] == '0') {
    header('Location: areaUsuario.php');
} else if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_REQUEST['admin'] == '1') {
    header('Location: areaAdm.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
        $erros = array();
        $username = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['senha']);
        $admin = $_REQUEST['admin'];

        if(empty($username) or empty($password)):
            $erros[] = "<li>Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos.</li>";
        else:
            $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0):
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1):
                $dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
                if ($dados['admin'] == '1'):
                    mysqli_close($connect);
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['senha'] = $password;
                    $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
                    header('Location: areaAdm.php');

                else:
                     mysqli_close($connect);
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['senha'] = $password;
                    $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
                    header('Location: areaUsuario.php');
                endif;

                else:
                    $erros[]="<li>Usuário e senha não conferem</li>";
                endif;
            else:
                $erros[]="<li>Usuário não cadastrado</li>";
            endif;
    endif;
endif;
?>
?>
```

Comment: essa varivavel 'admin' esta vindo como? via post? tem a superglobal _POST também. Quem sabe deva ser por lá que essa informação esta vindo... Outra ideia é já que a superglobal _Session também esta armazenando informação de login, por que nao armazenar informação se é admin ou nao? enfim só uma ideia.

Comment: Admin está vindo do database, como 1 ou 0. O request não funciona para este sentido?

Comment: A tentativa de realizar com o SESSION para "admin" também não ocorreu bem.

Comment: Olhando na documentação do php, vi um comentario la em baixo mostrando a diferença dos metodos _GET, _POST e _REQUEST... da uma olhada -> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Uso de $\_REQUEST ao invés de $\_GET, $\_POST e $\_COOKIE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37114/uso-de-request-ao-inv%c3%a9s-de-get-post-e-cookie)

Answer (score 1):

Resposta antiga->

```
Notei que no inicio chamou a classe do db, e provavelmente lá é feito o request para ver se o usuário é admin ou não, MAS... como ele vai fazer o request se ele ainda nem sabe quem é que ta logado? 

A `session_start()` esta vindo depois da chamada da classe.. ou seja se na classe houver um `_SESSION['login']` vai dar `null`... e por fim nao vai fazer o request corretamente...


Tente mover o `session_start` para cima e veja se funciona.


Caso não funcione ainda, seria interessante nao alterar a superglobal `_REQUEST` e continuar usando a superglobal `_SESSION` para guardar informações de logon..
Ao fazer logoff ela é facilmente destruida com `session_destroy` então acho que seria bacana utiliza-la.
```

Nova Resposta->

Para mim ficar na mesma sintonia que você estou tentando imaginar com mais clareza sua intenção que é "Não precisar refazer login se o usuario ainda não clicou em sair". Ai entramos em um problema.

A Session só existe em uma seção, se fechar essa seção obviamente ela acaba.

O LocalStorage perdura por mais tempo a informação no navegador. É possível seta-la e atualiza-la no frontend com js.

O LocalStorage não existe no PHP.

Quando abrir a tela de login a primeira coisa que terás que fazer é de fato verificar se ele já estava logado, e para isso precisa de uma informação no localStorage.

Podes no frontend pegar essa informação do localStorage e passar no ajax via metodo post para o backend..

```
//setar o local storage só depois de fazer login
var permisao= 0
var loginDoUsuario = 'joaoDaNika'
localStorage.setItem('admin', permisao)
localStorage.setItem('login', loginDoUsuario)

//ao abrir a pagina de login
//obter o localstorage
var admin = localStorage.getItem('admin')
var login = localStorage.getItem('login')
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'verify_login.php',
  data: ({admin,login})
  success: data=>{
    if(data=='aprovado'){
      //ir para dashboard
    }
  },
  error: erro=>{
   console.log(erro)
  }
})
```

No backend ->

```
<?php
    //verifica se tinha um usuario logado e se ele é admin
    if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['admin'])){
        if ($_POST['admin'] == '1'){ // se for admin deixa entrar sem refazer o login
            echo json_encode('aprovado');
        }else{
            echo json_encode('reprovado'); //se nao for lamento muito
        }
        die;
    }

    echo json_encode('reprovado'); //se ainda nao logou entao tem q logar
?>
```

Comment: O db_connect só faz a conexão com o banco de dados. Eu deixei dentro do script onde está esse código (ocultei aqui pra não ficar tão grande nesse tópico). Acha que eu ter colocado embaixo pode ter interferido no resultado?

Comment: Que informação esse db precisa pra poder ver se o usuario é admin ou nao? o login vindo do _SESSION correto? algo tipo if -> !isset($_SESSION['login'])-> ir para pagina de login, else -> verificar se esse login é admin ou nao..Enfim nao sei como estás capturando essa informação de admin..

Comment: Entendo, como sou bem leigo no assunto ainda, talvez esteja tendo um ruído na nossa comunicação por eu não saber expressar corretamente. Basicamente, tenho um DB que fiz completamente manual com: id (auto increment), username, password e admin. Esse status admin, eu coloquei para apenas dois usuários. Quando eles fazem login nessas contas, são direcionados para uma área especial de administrador. Vou adicionar no código do post a parte de baixo, para ver se o erro poderia estar nisso.